# Values changed after transforming numpy.arange() to list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

When you transform a numpy.arange array to a list in spyder3 (python3.7), the values change.

E.g. I created an array with `np.arange(0.4,2, 0.3)` and the output is like this which is normal:

```
Out[233]: array([0.4, 0.7, 1. , 1.3, 1.6, 1.9])
```

But when tranformed it with `list(np.arange(0.4,2, 0.3))`, the output turned to be:

```
Out[234]: 
[0.4,
 0.7,
 0.9999999999999999,
 1.2999999999999998,
 1.5999999999999996,
 1.8999999999999995]
```

So what's the problem? Is it a bug or something?

Comment: `numpy` displays array elements rounded to a reasonable common level.  A list displays each element independently.  Values aren't changed, it's just the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behavior. From the docs:

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases

Comment: Thanks! It confused me for a while.

Comment: But even with `linspace` you could get values like `1.6` that display as `1.59999...` depending of the context.